# Android Studio XML text is not centered inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have following chunk of `XML` code in Android Studio:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnEditPlants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btnEditPlant_Text"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ca_edit_plant"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNrOfCurrentlySelectedItemsCounter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_plants_selection_counter_rect"
        android:textColor="@color/md_theme_dark_primary"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="99"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The purpose of this [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) is to introduce selected items counter (showing `int` number) *overlayed* on a top of [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton). The counting works fine, however I cannot understand why text is not centered, as you can seen from design and runtime screenshots:
[image: TextView's text in design time]
[image: TextView's text at runtime]
Why [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView), named `tvNrOfCurrentlySelectedItemsCounter` is not centering the text. It has `android:textAlignment="center"` property set, as you can see. This `TextView` background is declared as [shape](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/md_theme_light_onSecondaryContainer" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    <size android:height="24dp"
        android:width="24dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: So you want the `2` (number) to be centered inside the "image"? Vertically? Horizontally, or both?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your text is not centered is because it's lacking `android:gravity="center"`, but I'd also change their width/height to `0dp` (both to the image and the text) so constraint layout does its job, it shouldn't make a difference in this case, but it's (to me) more explicit.

I replicated your layout and made that change (sorry I don't have your resources/colors, etc)

[image: ImageView with a centered text that says 99]

If you are wondering "why/which one to use" there's a more complex answer that goes back to api 17 if I correctly recall.

In short, `gravity` is a property of [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:gravity), whereas `textAlignment` comes from the plain [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textAlignment).

(which ultimately most/all Android widgets inherit from).

As you can see, textAlignment has a lot less options, as all views don't need (or at least don't offer) text or text customization at all, whereas the TextView needs them.

Is it confusing? Yes.

Should there be a more clear representation? Yes.

Welcome to Android Development.

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnEditPlants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btnEditPlant_Text"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ca_edit_plant"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNrOfCurrentlySelectedItemsCounter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_plants_selection_counter_rect"
        android:text="99"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Preview below what you want

[image]

Ignore the vector drawables I have used